# Is there an easy way to access the revision list of an unedited question?

Tags: feature-request, edit-history

There is an easy way to access the revision list of a question that was edited: to do it, I simply click on the link below the question that says "edited [date]".

I couldn't find an easy/built-in way to access this list on questions that have not had any edits. The only thing I could think of was changing "questions" in the URL to "posts" and changing the name of the question in the URL to "revisions".

Seeing the revision list on an unedited question might be desirable for example if someone wants to see the exact timeline of bounties, reasons for bounties, closing and reopening, tweets, etc.

So my question is:

> Does a simple way to do this already exist and I somehow missed it?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind installing a userscript in your browser, you can use one of the existing userscripts.

- [SE Modifications — Username autocomplete in comments, inline revision source, and utility links](https://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-a) adds a history link below every post if there isn't one already (as well as other features).
- [Add Hidden Links](https://stackapps.com/questions/2047/add-hidden-links) is more specialized.
- [Add Δimeline and ℜevisions Links](https://stackapps.com/questions/2371/add-imeline-and-evisions-links) adds these links in many question lists.

Comment: Timeline and revisions are also [among these "StackMarklets"](https://normalhuman.github.io/stackmarklets/).

Answer (score 3):

In the url, there is always the post number (this is post 6196).

You can go to ...stackexchange.com/*posts*/(post number)/revisions

where I put "posts" in italics to indicate that it changes too. For example, this post has never been edited, but you can go to

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/6196/revisions

for this question.

Comment: Thanks, but this is pretty much exactly what I was trying to describe in the second paragraph of my question ... I was hoping there might be some kind of link/button somewhere, without having to "guess" the URLs.